# If a table's rows are created by ng-repeat from return of one method, how set one of the rows by another method call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that gets all players on a team. That function is called on page load and then is used to create a row of data in a table like this `getTeamPlayers(teamName)`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in teamPlayers">
    <td><a href="#/players/{{player.id}}">{{player.name}}</a></td>
    <td><!-- want to put in here isMVP --></td>
</tr>
```

There's a second API call to find the MVP's player id. I want to:

1. Call that method `getLeagueMVP()`
2. Set the proper cell for the player that is the MVP (if they're on this team and their id matches the MVP player's id)

How do I do both #1 and #2?

Comment: Since angular does it's 2 way binding, couldn't you just do your getLeagueMVP and then update the teamPlayers array with that info?

Comment: @CalebO'Leary So update the `$scope.players` array? If I do that, it'll automatically update the table? And how do i call that second method? Where do i put that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in teamPlayers">
    <td><a href="#/players/{{player.id}}">{{player.name}}</a></td>
    <td ng-if="player.MVP == true">MVP</td>
</tr>



var teamPlayers = getTeamPlayers();
var mvp = getLeagueMVP();
for (var i = 0; i < teamPlayers.length; i++) {
    if (teamPlayers[i].id == mvp.id) {
        teamPlayers[i].mvp = true;
    }
}
```

You load players, then load mvp info, then look at all of the players, for each player, if this player's id is equal to the mvp's id, set the player's mvp value as true. Angular's data binding will understand that you've updated the array and should just update the ng-repeat table.

FYI I don't know any of your variable names or what these functions return =]